Wifi not showing in Asus Laptop
I tried installing Ubuntu 24.04 but there is no option of Wifi. When I checked, Mediatek Corp 7902 is used by asus which has not rolled out wifi drivers for Linux. What should I do now

See this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en

Are you using Ubuntu? Which supported release? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour].
